# How to make a winforms scrollbar wider using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

This program uses winforms and c# (no wpf).  I have a panel with buttons on it and getting it to scroll is no problem.  However, when the program is on a hi-resolution touch screen -- like a Surface 7 -- trying to touch in the exact right spot to get it to scroll is hit and miss.  I've searched and have yet to find a way to make the grab area (so to speak) of a vertical scroll bar wider so that when you touch the screen, the control actually picks up the event. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms

Comment: Thanks. There's some good info in there, but unfortunately, it seems to lead to scaling the entire panel... except for the scroll bar, which appears to remain constant.

Comment: It is a system setting.  Used to be easy to change but isn't anymore in Win10.  Best to ask at superuser.com.

Comment: You if you use a ScrollBar control instead of the standard Scrollbar, you can set its Width to whatever you want. Of course, you have to scroll the Form *manually*.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is DPI unaware, then it is enough to set the scrollbar width to `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the entire application? I need to just change one panel in the application.

Comment: No, it will affect only the scrollbar in question. I use it in the form constructor.

Comment: It seems like that's only a get... is there a set for that?

Comment: No, you need to use it like this: `myCustomScrollbar.Width = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`. So your scrollbar will have the same width as any other built-in scrollbars in scalable controls in the application. If controls are tool small in general, then it is enough to raise the DPI in Windows. If your application is DPI unaware, then upscaling happens by Windows automatically.

Comment: The application is completely winforms. So no auto scaling. The scrollbar isn't a custom scrollbar, it appears in the panel automatically, but there doesn't appear to be any way to access those types of properties.